# How can I solve the error when the user inputs only an "enter" in R?

Tags: r

I make a code based on a table game. At the beginning of the code, it must ask the player the name of the player, and when the player inputs an "enter", my code shows an error. I want that when the player inputs an "enter", the program says something like "This name is invalid", ask repeat asking the name of the player. Here is a part of my code:

```
  repeat{
    if(r==1){
      print("Name Player 1: ")
      name1=scan(,what="character",1)
      if(any(name1==gamers)){
        r=readline(prompt = "This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name? \n 1. Yes \n 2. No \n Select an option: ")
        if(r==0){
          r<-99
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print(...); name1=scan(...)`, I'd use `readline`, as such:

```r
while (!nzchar(name1 <- readline("Name Player 1: "))) TRUE
# Name Player 1:                     <-- me just hitting <enter>
# Name Player 1:                     <-- again
# Name Player 1: r2evans
name1
# [1] "r2evans"
```

You might prefer to allow a max number of failed attempts, though, instead of requiring the user interrupt the process with `ctrl-c`, so perhaps:

```r
tries <- 3L
while (tries > 0 && !nzchar(name1 <- readline("Name Player 1: "))) tries <- tries - 1L
# Name Player 1: 
# Name Player 1: 
# Name Player 1:
```

And the loop just stopped/exited. You "know" that the user chose to quit because after the loop, `tries == 0L` and `!nzchar(name1)` both indicate the user's intent.